# Difference between clear and new instantiation of a dictionary

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

Experts,
I have a piece of code where i create a dictionary and add it to a list. now i am using the same dictionary object to add next set of key value pairs to the dict. and add the same dictionary object again to the list. now in between the two operations i did Dictionary.clear().

which was a problem when i tried to retrieve the values. there was no values inside the ditionary. i was getting an index out of range error.
After i removed the clear instruction and instantiated again. this problem was solved !!!

but how ?

once u add to the dictonary then a copy of the object is added to the dictionary. whaat ever i do with the origial object , clear or what ever it should not affect the object which has already been added as a copy right ?

Comment: Can you show a [mcve]?

Comment: was not my question clear ? why it has to be voted down? can u please say

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> once u add to the dictonary then a copy of the object is added to the
> dictionary

This is not correct. When you add the dictionary to the list it adds a *reference* to the dictionary. When you then clear the dictionary the reference is still pointing to that same dictionary so you get an empty dictionary.

If you need a new dictionary then you should use `new`. Broadly speaking if you don't use `new` then you won't get a new one.